# How to detect edits from multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below functions that handle recording of changes to a change log when edits are made to a particular spreadsheet

Instead of monitoring changes to a single spreadsheet I would like to monitor changes to multiple spreadsheets (as array). How do I modify my code to create triggers for multiple spreadsheets?

```js
var model1Id = 'xxx';

var changelogId = 'yyy';

//creates onEdit trigger.
function createOnEditTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('catchEdits')
  .forSpreadsheet(model1Id)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}

//gets values from onEdit event and pushes this data to the changelog spreadsheet
function catchEdits(e){
  var spreadId = e.source.getId();
  var spreadName=e.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var cellAddress = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  var value = e.value;
  var user = e.user;
  var date = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(changelogId).appendRow([spreadId,spreadName,sheetName,cellAddress,oldValue,value,user,date]);
}
```

Comment: an onedit can only trigger for one sheet, but you should be able to copy this script to all of the source spreadsheets (keeping the same changeLog spreadsheet) and they will all write to it.

Comment: The script is presently  in a standalone sheet, not in a source sheet

Answer (score 1):

#### Question:

How do I modify my code to create triggers for multiple spreadsheets?

#### Answer:

If you have an array with the `IDs` of the different spreadsheets to monitor, you could just loop through this array and create a trigger for each corresponding spreadsheet.

#### Code sample:

```
function createOnEditTrigger(){
  const spreadsheetIds = ["spreadsheetId_1", "spreadsheetId_2", ...];
  spreadsheetIds.forEach(spreadsheetId => {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('catchEdits')
      .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- Please be aware that there is a limit of 20 triggers per user per script, so you cannot track more than 20 spreadsheet with a single script (see [Current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)).
- `e` doesn't have a property `SpreadsheetApp`, and `e.source` refers to the current spreadsheet, so I'd suggest you to change `var spreadName = e.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();` to `var spreadName = e.source.getName();` (see [onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)).